# Rendering a React component directly to HTML or Blade file

Tags: html, reactjs, laravel-blade

In Vue, there's this feature where you can render a registered component directly to an HTML or Laravel Blade file using `Vue.component()`
instead of mounting them to a parent component/element first. I wonder if such way is also possible with React, because I'm currently building a Laravel-React side project. You might suggest just create a root JS file and render the component with `ReactDOM.render()`, but that would be a hassle and it would flood the folder if I want to render multiple small components.

Answer (score 0):

In your view blade just add div like below

```
<div id="react-component-id" ></div>
```

and create component and render you html as below:

```
if (document.getElementById('react-component-id')) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <yourCreatedCompoennt />,
        document.getElementById('react-component-id')
    );
}
```

So it will not affect root level.